# PHP pagination products showing on one page only

Tags: php, pagination, shopping-cart

I am building a product catalog, that I want to be determined depending on users device. ie., if windows device show particular products. I have my products listing absolutely fine, however when implementing pagination, I am stuck.

I want only 6 items to be listed per page, I have more results. However more results are showing on the first page. When I select to go next, the ID number changes, to show it is showing me the next result, but it continues to show the same page, so obviously I am missing/got confused somewhere with my code. I'd appreciate any advice:

```
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$current_url = substr($current_url, 1);
$results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM apps A INNER JOIN device D ON D.DeviceID = A.DeviceID WHERE D.DeviceName = '$os'");    
$foundnum = mysqli_num_rows($results);
            if ($foundnum==0){
        echo "Sorry, there are currently no applications that are compatible with your device. Please try another option.";
    } else {
        echo "$foundnum applications are avaliable for '$os' devices:<p>";
        $per_page = 6;
            $start = $_GET['start'];
        $max_pages = ceil($foundnum / $per_page);

if(!$start)
            $start=0; 
        while($obj = $results->fetch_object()){
        $applicationid=$obj->ApplicationID;
        $start=0; 
        echo "<div class=\"col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4\">";
        echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
        echo "<div id='product'><a href='appproduct.php?id=$applicationid'><img src='images/app_images/$applicationid.jpg' alt='Product picture'/></div>";
        echo '<h2>'.$obj->ApplicationName.'</h2>';
        echo '<p>'.$obj->ApplicationDescription.'</p>';
        if($obj->App_cost=="0.00"){ 
                echo '<p>Free</p>';
            }else{
               echo '<p>£'.$obj->App_cost.'</p>';
            }
        echo '<button class="add_to_cart">Add To Cart</button>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$obj->ApplicationID.'" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
        echo '</form><br /><br /></div>';
     }   


//Pagination Starts
    echo "<center>";
    $prev = $start - $per_page;
    $next = $start + $per_page;                     
    $last = $max_pages - 1;
    if($max_pages > 1){   
    //previous button
        if (!($start<=0)) 
            echo "<a href='index.php?os=$os=Search+source+code&start=$prev'>Prev |</a> ";             
            //pages 
        $i = 0;   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $max_pages; $counter++){
            if($i == $start){
            echo " <a href='index.php?os=$os=Search+source+code&start=$i'><b> $counter |</b></a> ";
            }
            else {
                echo " <a href='index.php?os=$os=Search+source+code&start=$i'> $counter |</a> ";
            }  
        $i = $i + $per_page;                 
        }
    }      
//next button
if (!($start >=$foundnum-$per_page))
    echo " <a href='index.php?os=$os=Search+source+code&start=$next'> Next</a> ";    
}   
echo "</center>"
?>
```

Comment: Please fix the braces and indentation, because it the code is hard to read at the moment. You should also try to do the pagination via database, instead of loading all the results. If you had 100000 records and wanted to show only first 6 of them, you'd need to fetch 99994 records you might not use. Try to use `limit` of sql.

Comment: After following suggestions, it is now doing the pagination. However, when selecting to go to page 2, the pagination is not showing that page 2 is selected, it looks to the user like they are on page 1, and the 'next' option is not removing, presuming a count is going wrong somewhere? I have this pagination on another page and it works as i expect, but not on this page.

Comment: Make sure you are passing correctly the arguments for next values range on clicking the 'next' button and that they are correctly put into the query (obviously you have to repeat the query every time you click the button).

Comment: the results are displaying as expected, its purely now the page counting thats not right. where it is printing 1|2|next . when i select 2, the 'next' should go, and 2 should be showed as the one selected by being 'bolder'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to do the pagination via database, instead of loading all the results eagerly. If you had 100000 records and wanted to show only first 6 of them, you'd need to fetch 99994 records you might not use. Try to use `limit` of sql.

As for your problem with "bolding" current page number, you have logic error here:

```
    $i = 0;   
    for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $max_pages; $counter++) {
        if($i == $start){
            echo " <a href='index.php?os=$os=Search+source+code&start=$i'><b> $counter |</b></a> ";
        } else {
            echo " <a href='index.php?os=$os=Search+source+code&start=$i'> $counter |</a> ";
        }  
    $i = $i + $per_page;
```

According to this snippet you are comparing $i to $start, where $i is always equal to 0, so it will bold anything only on first page.

Comment: Just for future reference I solved the problem by putting: $start = $_GET['start']; $max_pages = ceil($foundnumapps/$per_page);
if(!$start)$start=0; Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use LIMIT in your MySQL query to only get a page of results at a time. It will look something like `LIMIT 0, 6`.

Answer (score 1):

change this line it will work

```
$results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM apps A INNER JOIN device D ON D.DeviceID = A.DeviceID WHERE D.DeviceName = '$os' LIMIT $_GET['start'], 6;");
```

but it's not the best way to do pagination or putting a variable straight from global variables. I would advise you to use at leat mysql escape string function in php